# How to find Apple ID used to set up my iPad

Tags: ipad, apple-id

How can I find out which Apple ID has been used to set up my ipad - it has been hacked and is now some years old and I am in the process of restoring this device.  This iPad is not listed on the Apple ID I have established.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Settings, click on iCloud, and it should tell you the ID.